# Trying to add condition for "draw" in TicTacToe

Tags: javascript

I wrote a Javascript program for the `draw` condition in the TicTacToe game.

**Condition**: When there are no cells left for the next move, It should display `draw`.

**Problem:** The program works fine when no cells left it displays `Draw`, but it doesn't check the condition for the win of circle or cross, after last move and directly shows Draw even when there's a winning result.

[Github](https://github.com/AnshShrivastava70/JavaScript-Projects/tree/main/TicTacToe)

I want the program to check whether there's a winning result before moving to `draw` as a result.

Here is the code snippet:-

```js
    const gameBoard = document.querySelector("#gameBoard");
    const infoDisplay = document.querySelector("#info");
    const newGame = document.querySelector("button");
    const startCells = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""];
    let go = "circle";
    infoDisplay.textContent = "Circle goes first!!!";
    
    function createBoard() {
      startCells.forEach((_cell, index) => {
        const cellElement = document.createElement("div");
        cellElement.classList.add("square");
        cellElement.id = index;
        cellElement.addEventListener("click", addGo);
        gameBoard.append(cellElement);
      });
    }
    createBoard();
    
    newGame.addEventListener("click", () => {
      resetGame();
    });
    
    function resetGame() {
      const allSquares = document.querySelectorAll(".square");
      allSquares.forEach((square) => {
        square.innerHTML = "";
        square.addEventListener("click", addGo);
        go = "circle";
        infoDisplay.textContent = "Circle goes first!!!";
      });
    }
    
    function addGo(e) {
      const goDisplay = document.createElement("div");
      goDisplay.classList.add(go);
      e.target.append(goDisplay);
      go = go === "circle" ? "cross" : "circle";
      infoDisplay.textContent = `It is now ${go}'s go.`;
      e.target.removeEventListener("click", addGo);
      checkScore();
    }
    
    function disableClicks() {
      const allSquares = document.querySelectorAll(".square");
      allSquares.forEach((square) => square.removeEventListener("click", addGo));
    }
    
    function checkScore() {
      const allSquares = document.querySelectorAll(".square");
      const winningCombos = [
        [0, 1, 2],
        [3, 4, 5],
        [6, 7, 8],
        [0, 3, 6],
        [1, 4, 7],
        [2, 5, 8],
        [0, 4, 8],
        [2, 4, 6],
      ];
    
      let circleWins = false;
      let crossWins = false;
    
      winningCombos.forEach((array) => {
        circleWins = array.every((cell) => {
          const firstChild = allSquares[cell].firstChild;
          return firstChild && firstChild.classList.contains("circle");
        });
    
        if (circleWins) {
          infoDisplay.textContent = "Circle wins!";
          disableClicks();
          return;
        }
    
        crossWins = array.every((cell) => {
          const firstChild = allSquares[cell].firstChild;
          return firstChild && firstChild.classList.contains("cross");
        });
    
        if (crossWins) {
          infoDisplay.textContent = "Cross wins!";
          disableClicks();
          return;
        }
      });
    
      let draw = [...allSquares].every((square) => {
        const firstChild = square.firstChild;
        return firstChild && (firstChild.classList.contains("circle") || firstChild.classList.contains("cross"));
      });
    
      if (draw) {
        infoDisplay.textContent = "Draw!";
        disableClicks();
      }
    }
```

```css
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Anton&family=Poppins:wght@100;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap');
    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
        /* font-family: 'Anton', sans-serif; */
        font-weight: 800;
    }
    
    :root{
        --clr-cross: #ff2972;
        --clr-circle: #00b0f1; 
        /* --clr-cross:linear-gradient(to right, #042439,#082D3F,#0D2F3B,#11333D,#153E44,#1F4C49); */
        /* --clr-cross:radial-gradient(circle, #042439,#082D3F,#0D2F3B,#11333D,#153E44,#1F4C49);
        --clr-circle:radial-gradient(circle, #2D0B0A, #320F0B, #38130D, #43170E, #4C1C10, #5D2F18 ); */
    }
    
    body {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        height: 100vh;
        background-color: #070a30;
        color: #fff;
        transition: .25s;
    }
    
    #gameBoard {
        width: 393px;
        height: 393px;
        background: black;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: center;
        transition: .25s;
    }
    
    .square {
        width: 131px;
        height: 131px;
        border: 2px solid #070a30;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    }
    
    .circle {
        height: 90px;
        width: 90px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background: #070a30;
        border: 15px solid var(--clr-circle);
        box-shadow: 0 0 10px var(--clr-circle), 0 0 30px var(--clr-circle), 0 0 50px var(--clr-circle);
    }
    
    .cross {
        height: 90px;
        width: 90px;
        position: relative;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        transform: rotate(45deg);
    }
    
    .cross::before,
    .cross::after {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        background: var(--clr-cross);
        background-clip: content-box;
        z-index: 1;
        box-shadow: 0 0 10px var(--clr-cross), 0 0 30px var(--clr-cross), 0 0 50px var(--clr-cross);
        
    }
    
    .cross::before {
        left: 50%;
        width: 30%;
        margin-left: -15%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    
    .cross::after {
        top: 50%;
        height: 30%;
        margin-top: -15%;
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    #display{
        height: 393px;
        width: 250px;
        position: relative;
        left: 0;
        top: 25px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
    }
    
    #display button {
        height: 36px;
        width: 117px;
        font-size: 1em;
        border-radius: 7px;
        background-color: #01bdab;
        border: none ;
        color: #070a30;
        transition: .25s;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    #display p{
        margin-top: 20px;
        font-size: larger;
    }
    
    #display  button:hover{
        opacity: 1.5;
        box-shadow:0 0 10px #01bdab, 0 0 30px #01bdab, 0 0 50px #01bdab;
    }
    
    #display button:active{
        opacity: .8;
    }
    
    #logo{
        position: absolute;
        top: 5px;
        left:20px;
        font-size: 2em;
        color: #a529ff;
    }
    
    img{
        width: 60px;
        height: 60px;
        margin-left: 5px;
        position: absolute;
        filter: invert(1);
    }
```

```html
<header>
    <div id="logo">
       <span style="color:#fe00f1">Tic</span>
       <span style="color: #ff2972">Tac</span>
       <span  style="color: #00b0f1;">Toe</span>
       <span id="img">
          <img src="tictactoe-logo1.png" alt="">
       </span>
    </div>
</header>
        <div id="gameBoard"></div>
        <div id="display">
            <button>NEW GAME</button>
            <p id="info"></p>
        </div>
```

Comment: Please include the relevant code in the question itself.

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to post the HTML and CSS, we expect enough code that we can reproduce your problem from the relevant, "*[mcve]*" code posted in your question in order that we can explore that code, and its functionality, to try to find the problem(s), and attempt to solve it/them.

Comment: Personally, instead of indivisual `circleWins` + `crossWins` + `draw` variables, I'd have a single variable e.g. `state` with the possible values of `null` (still playing), `"cross"` (crosses win), `"circle"` (circles win) and `"draw"`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are checking cross / circle wins in forEach loop and then you check draw after the forEach. That means that your program will display Win message correctly but after the forEach, condition for draw is also met so it will replace the text with winning mesage to draw message.

**At first**, move your variables `circleWins` and `crossWins` outside of your function `checkScore()`, because you are calling this function from function `addGo(e)` every time when user click to the board (and the variables are re-declared again and set to false)

**Then** add those variables into your function `resetGame()` to reset them after the game.

**Also** remove `return` statements from:

```
if (circleWins) {
    infoDisplay.textContent = "Circle wins!";
    disableClicks();
}
```

**and** from:

```
if (crossWins) {
    infoDisplay.textContent = "Cross wins!";
    disableClicks();
}
```

and now **Simple solution** is to edit your draw condition:

```
if (draw) {
    infoDisplay.textContent = "Draw!";
    disableClicks();
}
```

and display draw only when win condition not met - like this:

```js
if (draw && !circleWins && !crossWins) {
        infoDisplay.textContent = "Draw!";
        disableClicks();
    }
```

Now the draw text will be display only if `circleWins` and `crossWins`  are `false` (nobody won already).

**Working JSFiddle** solution: https://jsfiddle.net/bvsua4Lq/18/

**Another solution** can be to wrap your draw condition to another condition which is fired only when nobody won before:

```
if (!circleWins && !crossWins) {
  let draw = [...allSquares].every((square) => {
      const firstChild = square.firstChild;
      return firstChild && (firstChild.classList.contains("circle") || firstChild.classList.contains("cross"));
  });

  if (draw) {
      infoDisplay.textContent = "Draw!";
      disableClicks();
  }
}
```

Comment: That gave the same result, Draw shown even when circle won.

Comment: I improved my answer and I also included JSFiddle solution with updated code which works now!

Comment: Did you try running all the conditions of circle winning with the last move there are plenty of the ways circle wins but still result is draw...

Comment: On included JSFiddle I tried to possible combinations of Circle/Cross winning and also draw and it looks like it works as expected

Comment: There's a combination that I was trying from the beginning when I started looking for the solution and I tried that combination and that still shows Draw, while looking for another combination I found another one...